# Importing remote files via ES6 import

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I have an ES6 React app thats being compiled and bundled via browserify.

I have several import statements like:

```
import React from 'react/addons'
```

I also need to use an external library that creates an HTML widget, hosted on a CDN.  I've tried including the file before or after the bundle source:

```
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-7.9.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/build.js"></script>
```

When I try and reference the CDN provided object in the console, it works fine:

```
Auth0Lock
<-function Auth0Lock()...
```

Referencing it within the React app raises a syntax error.  I assume I need to  `import` it...but how?

Comment: Do you use this https://github.com/auth0/lock library ?

Comment: You can try install this library via `npm`, like `npm install auth0-lock` and then import it to your app. `import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';`

Comment: Ughhh.  That worked, thanks @Alexander.  Is it possible to import remote resources though?

Comment: no, now it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `auth0-lock` via npm, and use it as a local dependency

```
npm install auth0-lock --save
```

and then import it to your app like this

```
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';
```